# Some dynamics CRM contact entity records are being updated automatically in every 17 to 18 min

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

We are facing a very weird problem in our Dynamics CRM environment. There are two fields Birthdate and Owner. And these two fields are being updated in every 17-18 minutes automatically.

We can see the same in the audit log. We have validated our plugins code, workflows, system jobs, entity level business rules, automatic record creation and updating rules, and the scheduled .net application programs which are interacting with CRM. But, none of them seems culprit for this problem.

We have noted one point as well, the owner of the record and the modified by is always the same, it means these fields are being updated by the owner of those records themselves.

Could anybody advise further on this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like MS Product bug, and its fixed with latest bits. ie Upgrade to 9.0.2.1087

[Community thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/290126)

Comment: This question is asked by ME. :)

Comment: @MunavvarHusein yeah, I saw that. MHappick confirmed the resolution in answer. :)

Comment: @MunavvarHusein, so can you mark Arun's comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Do you use the CRM for Outlook plugin? By default, the synchronization is every 15 minutes.

Comment: Hello Nick, Thanks for the reply, I will validate it and share my findings back.